# http 500 and duplicate key value violates unique constraint - spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn how to handle Spring MVC and Hibernate exception through @ControllerAdvice. In my user table, I have unique name and email columns. So I want to display approximate message when the user violate the unique constraint:

This is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitRegisterForm(
        @RequestParam("userName") final String username, 
        @RequestParam("email") final String email,
        @RequestParam("password") final String password, Model model)
{
    String violatedContrainst = "Error to create a new account";
    Customer aCustomer = registerManager.registerCustomer(username, email, password);
        if(aCustomer != null) {
             LOGGER.info("Success register a new Account");
             return "/home";
         } else {
             LOGGER.info(violatedContrainst);
             throw new CustomerGenericException("E888", violatedContrainst);
         }
    }
}
```

My GlobalHandler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionController {
    private final static Logger LOGGER =
                    Logger.getLogger(GlobalExceptionController.class.getName());

    @ExceptionHandler(CustomerGenericException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleRegisterException(CustomerGenericException ex) {
        LOGGER.info("Register Hanler");
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("/register");
        model.addObject("errMsg", ex.getErrMsg());
        return model;
    }
}
```

My CustomerGenericException:

```
public class CustomerGenericException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3471542841610381393L;

    private String errCode;
    private String errMsg;

    public String getErrCode() {    return errCode; }
    public void setErrCode(String errCode) {    this.errCode = errCode; }

    public String getErrMsg() { return errMsg;  }
    public void setErrMsg(String errMsg) {  this.errMsg = errMsg;   }

    public CustomerGenericException(String errCode, String errMsg) {
        this.errCode = errCode;
        this.errMsg = errMsg;
    }
}
```

And this is my Service:

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackOn=CustomerGenericException.class)
public Customer registerCustomer(String name, String email, String password) {
    LOGGER.info("Persist a new Customer Entry");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Login login = new Login();      
    if( login.validateUsername(name) && login.validateEmail(email)
            && login.validatePassword(password)) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        // Set login account
        login.setName(name);
        login.setEmail(email);
        login.setPassword(encodedPassword(password));

        customer.setLogin(login);   
        login.setCustomer(customer);
        login.setEnabled(true);

        registerDao.add(customer);
        return customer;
    }
    return null;
}
```

So whenever I violate the unique constraint, I got the http 500 status and in the console, it displays duplicate value violation. How can I handle the exceptions in spring mvc and hibernate correctly?

Comment: maybe it is because your registerDao.add(customer); throw an hibernate exception that is never catched. Try to encapsulate the dao call in a try catch, in the catch log the error en return null;

Comment: my registerDao.add(customer) basically is session.save(customer). I don't want my daos become boilerplate, so I dont really want to surround every dao function with try-catch blog but I prefer to let spring handle it for me. I think it is better that way tho

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate Controller to handle such exceptions. See this link for reference:

[Exception Handling in Spring MVC](http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc), Using @ExceptionHandler

Answer (score 0):

The exception in your code is thrown by the following line

```
Customer aCustomer = registerManager.registerCustomer(username, email, password);
```

which must be a hibernate exception, and the code written below this line is never executed. On the other hand your `ExceptionHandler` will only handle `CustomerGenericException`, which is never thrown from your controller.
You have a lot of ways to handle this, depends on how you actually want it.
For me the better way would be to make use of Spring Exception Translation, see [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html)

basically you need to make sure that you have a exception handler to handle the particular type of exception.